# Dandelion Datatables Export Button onclick causes a is undefined Jquery error

Tags: spring, datatables, dandelion

I am trying to export data from a Dandelion Datatables table.

`<table id="simlist" dt:table="true" dt:export="xlsx">`

Button is visible but browser console returns

> TypeError: a is undefined[Learn More]

I see Jquery2.2.3 before any dandelion scripts.
Dandelion Datatables version 1.1.0
Thymeleaf 2.1.2.RELEASE
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using filter-based or controller-based export?

In case of the first you must register Dandelion-Datatables filter ([see doc 6.2](https://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#6-2-filter-based-exports)), and for the controller-based export ([see doc 6.3](https://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#6-3-controller-based-exports)) you must write and register controller.

Comment: Hi Borut, its a Controller based export and it works fine if I do not customize the URL for the export link generated by Dandelion.  The controller is registered and generated excel files fine.  Its just a jQuery error during the onclick event generated by Dandelion.